# How to order documents by a dynamic property in Mongoid

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I am using Mongoid to store a series of geocoded listings. These listings need to be sorted by price and proximity. The price of every listing is a field in the database whereas distance is a dynamic property that is unique for every user.

```
class Listing
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :price

  def distance
    get_distance(current_user.location,coordinates)
  end
end
```

How can I sort these documents by distance? I tried `@listing.desc(:distance)` and that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short (and unhelpful) answer is: you can't.

Mongoid does have the ability to [query based on 2d co-ordinates](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#near) though, then you could update your controller to do something like this:

```
@listings = Listing.near(current_user.location)
```

Which I believe will return your listings in order of distance.

On a side note, I noticed that your `Listing` model is referring to your `current_user` object, which kinda breaks the MVC architecture, since your models shouldn't know anything about the current session.